# next-i18next has bug Apostrophe is displayed as &#39;

Tags: i18next, apostrophe, next-i18next

I am using next-i18next. I have a bug has bug Apostrophe is displayed as `&#39;`
How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It was [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation), specifically `escapeValue: false`.